# Ставится ли запятая перед словом «какие»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, орфография

*коротко о том, какие фотографии я отправляю  маме из магазина*

Answer (score 1):

*Коротко о том, **какие** фотографии я отправляю маме из магазина.*

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении (ССП) между главным и придаточным предложениями. Это придаточное изъяснительное, союзное слово КАКИЕ.